Bivalve Respiration
Minor question:  Is it "Mollusk" or "Mollusc"?  I've encountered both spellings, and am unsure which is correct.  For now, I'll use the "-k" spelling, but if anyone can correct me, that'd also be helpful.
EDIT:  This part has been addressed and revisions to the question have been made.  Thank you!
Howdy!  I'm doing some spec-evo stuff, and came upon this particular question about Mollusks - particularly bivalves like clams and oysters.  I understand that, like many mollusks, bivalves pass water across their gills with siphons.  Water flows into their bodies, across the gills, then flows back out, in a manner like this:

I am also led to believe that, like many other mollusks, they also use this technique as a means to remove bodily waste and gametes/larvae from within their body cavities.  The anus and gonopores reside within the body on the exhalant/outcurrent side, and any waste or reproductive cells are expelled along with water flowing out, like this:

My question is this: how do bivalves prevent this waste material from getting stuck in their gills?  I would assume that waste material interacting with the gill would lead to infection or damage, and it doesn't seem as though any mollusk encounters the problem of accidentally breathing their own waste.  If these diagrams are accurate, then it likely has something to do with how water flows within their bodies that prevents "backdrafts", so to speak.  But I don't understand how exactly this works, and my own research has turned something of a dead end.  Any advice would be immensely appreciated.
Image source:
https://youtu.be/IWzOGB7bBuA?si=LT6s_pzayu6P2Gaq

Both "Mollusk" and "Mollusc" have existed since the 1830s; "Mollusk" used to be more common, then in the late XIX century "Mollusc" surpassed it in UK and Dominions, while the former remained predominant in the USA. The proponents of Mollusc abide by the rule that the vernacular name should be the Latin word "Mollusca" minus the last letter (or something like that); the proponents of Mollusk mantain that the preferred way to write the sound /sk/ at the end of an English word should be "sk" (or something like that).

Mollusk (and history) guy ->  https://web.archive.org/web/20120303002304/http://www.conchologistsofamerica.org/articles/y1996/9609_rosenberg.asp
$$$$
Mollusc guy -> Brusca & Brusca. Invertebrates (2nd ed.), chapter 20, footnote.
